# Fractional representation of fundamental solution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, functional-calculus, heisenberg-group

I'm reading Lieb and Frank's paper 'Sharp constants in several inequalities on
the Heisenberg group' these days. And I am really confused about the Proposition 4.1 there.

They define the 'Laplacian' $\mathcal L_s$ on the Heisenberg group by

$$
\mathcal{L}_s:=|2 \mathcal{T}|^s \frac{\Gamma\left(|2 \mathcal{T}|^{-1} \mathcal{L}+\frac{1+s}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(|2 \mathcal{T}|^{-1} \mathcal{L}+\frac{1-s}{2}\right)}
$$where $\mathcal L=-\cfrac 14 \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2+Y_i^2)$ and $\mathcal T=\partial_t$ with $X_i, Y_i$ are the left ivariant vector fileds on Heisenberg group $\mathbb H^n$.

More precisely,
$$
\left(\mathcal{L}_s^{-1} \delta_0\right)(u)=a_s|u|^{-Q+2 s}, \quad a_s=\frac{2^{n-s-1} \Gamma^2\left(\frac{Q-2 s}{4}\right)}{\pi^{n+1} \Gamma(s)},
$$
where $\delta_0$ denotes a Dirac delta at the point $0$ . And **then they said**:

For given $\lambda$, we abbreviate $s:=(Q-\lambda) / 2$ and define
$$
k:=a_s^{-1 / 2} \mathcal{L}_s^{-1 / 2} \delta_0
$$
Since $\mathcal{L}_s^{-1 / 2} \mathcal{L}_s^{-1 / 2}=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}$, this function satisfies
$$
\int_{\mathbb{H}^n} k\left(w^{-1} u\right) k\left(v^{-1} w\right) d w=|u^{-1} v|^{-\lambda}.
$$

It seems that they just admitted that **$k$ is a funtion**. But I can't see this.

In my concerns, the equality
$$
k:=a_s^{-1/2}\mathcal L_s^{-1/2}\delta_0
$$
is in the sense of distribution.

Of course, when we deal with $-\Delta$ on $\mathbb R^n$, we know that
$$
(-\Delta)^{-1/2}\delta_0= |x|^{1-n}
$$
is indeed a function. But **how can I see the defined $k$ is realy a function**.

Thanks in advance! I think it could be thought in the sense of convolution, since we know
$$
((-\Delta)^{-1}\delta_0) (f)=f*|x|^{-n+2}
$$
for functions in $\mathbb R^n$.